# Entity Framework предлагает некорректное имя поля

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, firebird

У меня в БД есть две таблицы, BUNTS, которая хранит информацию о кусках металла

```
CREATE TABLE BUNTS (
BUNTCODE         INTEGER NOT NULL,
BUNTNAME         VARCHAR(20),
BUNTSTEEL        INTEGER,
......
```

);

и poll_weight_bunts, которая хранит информацию об операциях, выполненных на этих кусках

```
CREATE TABLE POLL_WEIGHT_BUNTS (
    PWBCODE            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PWBBUNTCODE        INTEGER,
    PWBDEPARTMENTFROM  INTEGER,
    PWBDEPARTMENTTO    INTEGER
```

....
    );

Отношение один-ко-многим. Я прицепил эти таблицы на модель  и все прекрасно работало.
Недавно я решил добавить поле в таблицу BUNTS, которое ссылается на последнюю выполненную операцию на бунте

```
BUNTLASTOPER     INTEGER
```

И теперь мои модели выглядят так

```
[Table("BUNTS")]
    public class Bunt
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("BUNTCODE")]
        public int? Code { set; get; }
        [Column("BUNTNAME")]
        public string Name { set; get; }
        [Column("BUNTSTEEL")]
        public int? SteelCode { set; get; }
        [Column("BUNTLASTOPER")]
        public int? LastOperationID { set; get; }
        [ForeignKey("LastOperationID")]
        public BuntOperation LastOperation { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<BuntOperation> Operations { set; get; }
}



[Table("POLL_WEIGHT_BUNTS")]
    public class BuntOperation
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("PWBCODE")]
        public int? Code { set; get; }
        [Column("PWBBUNTCODE")]
        public int? BuntCode { set; get; }
        [ForeignKey("BuntCode")]
        public Bunt Bunt { set; get; }
        [Column("PWBDEPARTMENTFROM")]
        public int? DepartmentFromCode { set; get; }
```

.....
    }

После того, как я это сделал, когда я пытаюсь выбрать операции

```
return _context.Operations;
```

EF генерирует мне SQL-запрос с некорректным полем Bunt_Code

```
SELECT 
"B"."PWBCODE" AS "PWBCODE", 
"B"."PWBBUNTCODE" AS "PWBBUNTCODE", 
"B"."PWBDEPARTMENTFROM" AS "PWBDEPARTMENTFROM", 
....
"B"."Bunt_Code" AS "Bunt_Code"
FROM   "POLL_WEIGHT_BUNTS" AS "B"
```

Походе, что EF ищет поле, которое является внешним  ключом к таблице BUNTS, и не находит. Поэтому генерирует поле "Bunt_Code", которого нет в таблице. Но у меня уже есть свойство "Bunt" в классе BuntOperation, которое ссылается на BUNTS. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас теперь есть две разные связи между одними и теми же таблицами - и EF некорректно определил какое свойство какому соответствует. Если точнее, то EF теперь думает, что `BuntOperation.Bunt` соответствует `Bunt.LastOperation`, а не `Bunt.Operations`.

Для того, чтобы задать соответствие явно, следует перегрузить метод `OnModelCreating` - и написать там примерно следующее:

```
builder.Entity<Bunt>().HasOptional(b => b.LastOperation).WithMany();
builder.Entity<Bunt>().HasMany(b => b.Operations).WithRequired(op => op.Burn);
```

Возможно,первая строка покажется немного странной - ведь операция может быть последней только для одного `Burn` - но вашу схему БД проще всего представить именно так.

Вообще, при использовании модели CodeFirst над существующей БД проще всего не следить за всеми генерируемыми запросами - а позволить EF создать другую БД с нуля как он ее представляет - а потом проверить соответствие результата вашим ожиданиям. Когда соответствие достигнуто - можно начинать использовать существующую БД.

Comment: Спасибо за столь быстрый и полезный совет! Действительно, помогло!