# Как правильно: перегрузка или переопределение?

Tags: c#, терминология

В одних статьях пишут перегрузка, в других пишут переопределение. Тоже самое с наследниками и производными. По смыслу это одно и то же, но как правильно:

- перегрузка или переопределение?
- в наследниках или в производных?

Чтобы далеко не ходить за примерами я стал искать прямо на сайте ответы по интересующим меня методам [Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) и [OnModelCreating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx), которые описаны в документации как виртуальные, и нашел следующие ответы:

- *"следует перегрузить метод OnModelCreating - и написать там примерно следующее"*
  [27 май '15 в 15:53](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/426555/201326), Pavel Mayorov, 9,255
- *"базовый класс всех типов-значений, перегружает метод Equals"*
  [30 сен '15 в 0:01](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454619/201326), VladD, 74k
- *"Переопределите Equals так, чтобы он сравнивал два экземпляра"*
  [23 дек '15 в 8:52](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477173/201326), PashaPash, 20.1k

Из контекста следует, что в ответах говорят о виртуальных методах.
Получается, что перегрузка и переопределение - это одно и тоже.
Хотелось бы понять как правильно: перегрузка или переопределение?

**UPD**: (2/10/2016 8:52 PM)

Перегрузка и переопределение, как [сказал rdom](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/490787/201326): это ***абсолютно разные вещи***.
VladD внес [исправления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/454619/revisions) в свой ответ.
Ошибки в других ответах, надеюсь, также будут исправлены.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> перегрузка или переопределение?

По смыслу - это абсолютно разные вещи.

**Перегрузка (Overloading)** - это возможность использовать одинаковые имена в пределах одного класса у методов сходных по своей сути, но не реализации,за счет расширения понятия имени метода до сигнатуры.
Подробнее в соседнем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/490768/198316)

**Переопределение (Overriding)** - относится к **виртуальным** и **абстрактным** методам. Это возможность замены виртуального или реализация абстрактного наследуемого метода базового класса методом производного класса.

Пример:

```
class A
{
    virtual void SomeMethod(int par1, double par2) { }

    //Делаем перегруженный вариант метода для другого набора параметров
    void SomeMethod(double par1, int par2) {}
}

class B : A
{
    //Переопределяем унаследованный виртуальный метод
    override void SomeMethod(int par1, double par2) { }
}
```

**UPD**

> в наследниках или в производных?

тут разночтений нет. **Производный класс**, **класс наследник**, а также принятые в Java **суб-класс** или **подкласс**, являются **синонимами**. Также синонимами являются **базовый класс**, **класс предок**, **супер-класс**(java) и **над-класс**(java).

Дабы не плодить споры: я использую перевод принятый в MSDN. В различных источниках могут использоваться другие варианты перевода. В любом случае, первичным остается смысл оригинальных терминов на английском.

Comment: Ваш ответ не совсем корректен, если я добавлю метод с `new`, то я сделаю замену метода, но это не будет overriding. Overriding это про виртуальные методы, а не про всё подряд

Comment: Стоит процитировать главное из ответа по ссылке здесь, а ссылку оставить для тех кому интересны дополнительные подробности

Comment: обновил с учетом замечаний и добавил пример для наглядности

Comment: @rdorn Спасибо за ответ, но меня терзают сомнения в правильности вашего ответа. Посмотрите пожалуйста примеры, которые я добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @Grizlov да, так тоже иногда говорят, тут нужно следить за контекстом. Как и везде в русском языке =) но оригинальное значение терминов от этого не меняется.

Comment: @Grizlov все иногда ошибаются или используют слова не по назначению. Взять хотя бы наше общее "отксерить", ну какое отношение имеет копирование к компании производителю копиров? и что мешает сказать "откиосерить" или "отрикохить" например?

Comment: "overriding" все же обычно переводится как "перекрытие". По крайней мере в книгах "Диалектики-Вильямс" overload - перегрузка, а overriding - перекрытие.

Comment: @Harry погрешность перевода, увы, всегда больше нуля, т.к. обычно перевод делают люди знакомые с языком, а не предметной областью. Именно поэтому я предпочитаю в спорных моментах использовать оригинальный английский текст, а не перевод.